# How to add certificates to Kube config file

Tags: kubernetes

I have an local Kubernetes environment and I basically copy **.kube/config** file to my local and added "**context**", "**users**", and "**cluster**" informations to my current "**.kube/config**" file. That's ok, I can connect to my local file.

But I want to add these informations to my local config file with commands.

So regarding to this page, I can use "**certificate-authority-data**" as parameter like below:   ---> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

```
PS C:\Users\user\.kube> kubectl config --kubeconfig=config set-cluster local-kubernetes --server=https://10.10.10.10:6443 --certificate-authority-data=LS0tLSAASDASDADAXXXSDETRDFDJHFJWEtGCmx0YVR2SE45Rm9IVjAvQkdwRUM2bnFNTjg0akd2a3R4VUpabQotLS0tLUVORCBDADADADDAADS0tXXXCg==
Error: unknown flag: --certificate-authority-data
See 'kubectl config set-cluster --help' for usage.
PS C:\Users\user\.kube>
```

But it throws error like above. I'm using kubernetes latest version.

How can I add these informations to my local file with kubectl config command?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/501): `kubectl config set-cluster xyz --embed-certs --certificate-authority <(echo $CACERT)` ?

Comment: But I don't have any .crt and .key files, except only .kube/config file and these keys in there. So if I copy keys to another -key file, it's not working.

Comment: Can you then describe what do you want to achieve here in more detail? From your description it is not clear to me what do you want to do. Do you want to copy config on new machine or generate new certs for new user?

Comment: No, at the K8s server, .kube/config exist and also related keys in that config file. These are "certificate-authority-data", "client-certificate-data" and "client-key-data". How can I add these keys' values(that means lots of character like in my original post) to the my local config file?

Answer (score 17):

Possible solution for that is to use `--flatten` flag with config command:

```
➜  ~ kubectl config view --flatten=true
```

> flatten the resulting kubeconfig file into self contained output
> (useful for creating portable kubeconfig files)

That can be also exported to a file (portable config):

```sh
kubectl config view --flatten > out.txt
```

You can read more about kube config in [Mastering the KUBECONFIG file](https://ahmet.im/blog/mastering-kubeconfig/) document.

Once you run this command on the server where the appropriate certificate are present you will receive base64 encoded keys: `certificate-authority-data`, `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data`.

Then you can use the command provided in the [official config document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#config):

```
➜  ~ kubectl config set clusters.my-cluster.certificate-authority-data $(echo "cert_data_here" | base64 -i -)
```

Then you have to replace `(echo "cert_data_here" | base64 -i -)` with data from flatten config file.

Worth to mention that this info is also available with `-help flag` for kubectl config:

```
kubectl config set --help   
Sets an individual value in a kubeconfig file

 PROPERTY_VALUE is the new value you wish to set. Binary fields such as 'certificate-authority-data'
expect a base64 encoded string unless the --set-raw-bytes flag is used.

 Specifying a attribute name that already exists will merge new fields on top of existing values.

Examples:
  # Set certificate-authority-data field on the my-cluster cluster.
  kubectl config set clusters.my-cluster.certificate-authority-data $(echo "cert_data_here" | base64
-i -)
```

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl config set-cluster` only accepts `--certificate-authority`, which needs a file.

You can simply create the file by base64 decode your string.

```
echo LS0tLSAASDASDADAXXXSDETRDFDJHFJWEtGCmx0YVR2SE45Rm9IVjAvQkdwRUM2bnFNTjg0akd2a3R4VUpabQotLS0tLUVORCBDADADADDAADS0tXXXCg== | base64 -d > cert.pem

kubectl config --kubeconfig=config set-cluster local-kubernetes --server=https://10.10.10.10:6443 --certificate-authority=cert.pem
```